# MYSQL UPDATE's in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to update the utility table while also updating the tenants table if the user choose yes or no but it only updates the second table.

```
    <form action="" id="FORM" method="POST">
        Electricity: <select id ="elec" name="elec">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select><br>
<input type="submit"  name="btn" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
```

used form to get the yes/no answers from the user

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
    $roomid = $_POST['room'];
    $elec = $_POST['elec'];
    $gas = $_POST['gas'];
    $wat= $_POST['wat'];
    $wifi = $_POST['wifi'];
$sql="UPDATE utility SET electricity='$elec', gas='$gas', water='$wat', wifi='$wifi' WHERE roomid='$roomid'";
    if ($elec == 'No') {
    $sql ="UPDATE tenant SET monthlypay = monthlypay-150 WHERE roomid ='$roomid'";
}   else if ($elec == 'Yes') {
        $sql ="UPDATE tenant SET monthlypay = monthlypay+150  WHERE roomid ='$roomid'";
    }
if ($gas == 'No') {
    $sql ="UPDATE tenant SET monthlypay = monthlypay-150 WHERE roomid ='$roomid'";
}   else if ($gas == 'Yes') {
        $sql ="UPDATE tenant SET monthlypay = monthlypay+150  WHERE roomid ='$roomid'";
    }
if ($wat == 'No') {
    $sql ="UPDATE tenant SET monthlypay = monthlypay-150 WHERE roomid ='$roomid'";
}   else if ($wat == 'Yes') {
        $sql ="UPDATE tenant SET monthlypay = monthlypay+150  WHERE roomid ='$roomid'";
    }
if ($wifi == 'No') {
    $sql ="UPDATE tenant SET monthlypay = monthlypay-150 WHERE roomid ='$roomid'";
}   else if ($wifi == 'Yes') {
        $sql ="UPDATE tenant SET monthlypay = monthlypay+150  WHERE roomid ='$roomid'";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: It would be easier if you showed us where your "yes"/"no" variables are set.

Comment: edited in where I got the yes/no answers

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Anyway an obvious issue here is that you're using `$sql` to store two different SQL strings. It doesn't appear that you ever execute `"UPDATE utility SET electricity='$elec', gas='$gas', water='$wat', wifi='$wifi' WHERE roomid='$roomid'";` before you give another different value to `$sql` through your if/else statements. So the simple reason it doesn't execute the first query is because you never told it you. instead you over-wrote the query with something else before you had used it. As a rule of thumb, don't use the same variable name to store two different things!

Comment: ...oh and make sure you execute your queries (safely, as per my first comment!). Just creating the SQL string doesn't actually run the query. You haven't shown any code at at all which would execute any of the queries, but assuming since you've stated "it...updates the second table" (which I take to mean `tenant`, although you didn't make it very clear) that somewhere later on you are actually running that query.

Comment: Even after you sort that, you still have a logical issue because it will only ever execute the "wifi" version of your query - because again you keep overwriting the value of $sql before you use it. And if the intention is to execute one `UPDATE tenant...` query for each answer, then that's really inefficient, as well as involving lots of needless repetition of the same SQL in your code. All of them change the same value in the table.

Comment: So just use the if/else's to keep a running total (in a variable) of the amount by which the monthlypay should be changed (by keep adding or subtracting amounts from that variable depending on each answer), and then you can use the final value of that, variable after all the questions have been assessed, in a single query to update the `tenant` table by the correct amount at the end.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the input, can you post the running total variable if possible.

Comment: Well it's just a simple number variable. e.g. you'd start with `$monthlyPay = 0;` or similar, and then in the if/else's you'd do something like `if ($elec == 'No') $monthlyPay -= 150; else if ($elec == 'Yes') $monthlyPay += 150;`. Repeat the same pattern for each utility. Then you can simply use the $monthlyPay value as a parameter in the `UPDATE tenant` query in place of the hardcoded `150` you've had up to now. And you'd only need one UPDATE query, to be run after all the if/else statements have finished.